# I need help on Styling the Window Border with AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I'm creating an application using AHK, I'd like to change the default Window Border to a Style like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArWHt.png

Background Colour: #2B2D39
Text Colour: #474d65

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

```
Gui, Border, Style, 2B2D39, 474d65
```

Comment: Do you mean the title bar (based on the picture)? I can't say definitively, but I don't believe this is possible in normal AHK. It creates WinForm GUIs, so I think the color scheme of the title bar is controlled by the OS. The color scheme can be changed, but it's per computer and affects all WinForm-style windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, but probably you need to convert your color (e.g., colour) codes to AHK Hex format. You can also get around the WinForm stuff with `WinSet` or GDI. I actually often start with a HTA as my front end and can then control it with javascript or jquery or whatever.

Lots of good examples and samples here: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3851

Comment: Wow, some really awesome examples there (some even with tutorials)! Can you use `WinSet` to change the titlebar colors? I'd imagine a course of action would be to make a captionless GUI with a picture acting as a fake titlebar as shown here: http://jszapp.com/make-beautiful-graphical-user-interface-15-lines-less/